# Segment packing algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I came up with an interesting (I think) problem and can't find a solution. Is this NP-Complete maybe (like some other packing problems)? If so, how would the reduction go?

> We are given an array **1..n** with some elements occupied and list of
>   lengths of segments. The question is, can we pack those segments into
>   this array so that no segments overlap with each other and occupied elements?

Example, array: |_ _ _ _ x _ _ _ _ _ _| (x - occupied, and the underscore means it's free) and lengths: 3, 3, 4. The answer in this case is YES, because in fact we have two containers in this array: 4, 6 and we can pack first two segments in container with capacity 6 and the last one to the first container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to formulate the reduction with the [partition-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) as base-problem.

#### Partition-problem

The partition problem is the task of deciding whether a given multiset S of positive integers can be partitioned into two subsets S1 and S2 such that the sum of the numbers in S1 equals the sum of the numbers in S2. (from wiki-link above).

Example:

- Given S = {3,1,1,2,2,1}
- Valid solution to the partition problem is the two sets S1 = {1,1,1,2} and S2 = {2,3}
- Both sets sum to 5, and they partition S.

#### Reduction

- Given: a partition-problem instance like S = {3,1,1,2,2,1}
- Sum up the values: n = sum(X)
- Create the array |+++...x***...| where |+| = n/2; |*| = n/2 (cardinalities)

  - |+++++x*****| (the gap acts as class-split)
- Add the segments equal to the integer-sizes

  - segments = {###, #, #, ##, ##, #}
- Solve the problem with some algorithm for the problem above

  - Valid solution: |### # # x ## ## #| (white-space only introduced for visualization)
    This reduction is doable in polynomial-time (and it's clear that the original problem is in NP). This means, the original problem is NP-complete.